# Sorting elements in AngularJS for nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I am using bootstrap to display a grid of projects with each row having 3 columns. In order to accomplish this, I am using ng-repeat twice like below.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="chunk in projects">
  <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="project in chunk | orderBy:'title'">
    {{project.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to sort the project based on its title field. Applying a filter only sorts a subset of the whole list i.e. sorts at the chunk level rather than the projects level.

```
var projects = [[{"title":"Z"},{"title":"A"},{"title":"M"}],
  [{"title":"Z"},{"title":"A"},{"title":"M"}]];
```

After the orderBy happens, the rows are A M Z, A M Z. How do I get it to display A A M, M Z Z?

Here is the [plunk](https://embed.plnkr.co/3UGSq5VnYAaFhEWOxRZa/) for the above problem.
//EDIT : The above plunk points to the solution because I updated the plunk.

Comment: Why would you expect that ordering on the inner ng-repeat would affect the outer?  Either order on the outer or consider flattening your data structure into something that more closely resembles your output.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to flatten the structure out more.

Comment: From what I understood, you are suggesting that I modify projects as var = [{"title":"A"},{"title:"B"},{"title":"C"},{"title":"A"},{"title:"B"},{"title":"C"}]. This creates a problem another problem. I want the outer div with class row to conatin exactly three inner divs with class col-sm-4. It cannot be achieved with the suggested data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem finally through filter chaining. I used angular-filter module/library but this can be even done without angular-filter.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ExampleController as exampleVm">
<div class="row" ng-repeat="chunk in exampleVm.projects|  chunkBy: 'title' | groupBy : 3">
  <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="project in chunk">
    {{project.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I flattened the array and made it look like this.

```
var projects = [{"title:Z"},{"title":"A"},{"title":"M"},{"title:Z"},{"title":"A"},{"title":"M"}]
```

In the filter chain, I order the elements in the flattened array first by title and then divide it into subarrays of 3 elements each. Hope this helps.

You can find the plunk [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/3UGSq5VnYAaFhEWOxRZa/).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a custom filter that will turn your sub-arrays into a single array. The whole point of having separate arrays would be to isolate the contents, which is the opposite of what you want.

Filter:

```
yourAppModule
.filter('titleSort', function(){
    return function(input){
        var fullArray = []; //Will be the output array    
        for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++)            
            fullArray.concat(input[i]);
            //Iterates through all the arrays in input (projects)
            //and merges them into one array            
        fullArray = fullArray.sort(function(a,b){return a.title>b.title});
            //Sorts it by the title property
        var chunks = [];
        var currentChunk;
        for(var i=0;i<fullArray.length;i++){
            if(i%3===0){
                currentChunk = [];
                chunks.push(currentChunk);
            }
            currentChunk.push(fullArray[i]);   
        }
        return chunks;
    };
} ...
```

Now your view can be this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="project in projects | titleSort">
    {{project.title}}
</div>
```

Comment: I want the div with class row to contain exactly 3 divs with class col-sm-4. So if there are more than 3 projects in projects variable, I want the extra projects to go inside a new div with class row.

Comment: @PravinUmamaheswaran I edited it to re-split the full array after sorting it.

Comment: I tried your edited solution. I get a $rootScope.infdig error. Turns out, the model for ng-repeat keeps on getting changed each time the filter gets called which results in $digest getting called an infinite number of times. I'm trying to solve this issue using $scope.$watch. Will update if I work out a solution.

Comment: Ok, well that sounds like a problem external to the filter. What I gave is ultimately some pretty simply rearrangement in an isolated scope.

Answer (score 0):

try this. may be help you.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[])
app.controller('ctrl',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.data = [[{"title":"Z"},{"title":"A"},{"title":"M"}],
  [{"title":"Z"},{"title":"A"},{"title":"M"}]];
  
  $scope.data2 = [];
  angular.forEach( $scope.data,function(d){
    angular.forEach(d,function(d1){
      $scope.data2.push(d1);
      })
    })
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="item item-checkbox">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="project in data2 | orderBy:'title'">
    {{project.title}}
  </div>
</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: I am quite new to angular js and I did not quite understand the angular.forEach() block of code. I tried to use this code as it is but the grid columns won't print. I don't know if I am messing something up or not.