# Angular2: ngFor multiple objects per row in table

Tags: angular, ngfor

My component has an array of strings I want to display in a table.  However, I want the table to have 4 columns per row.  How can I use *ngFor to show 4 strings per row?

I'm aware there are solutions without using tables, but in this case I'm really interested in using a table.

Comment: Please show some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I recommend you use a table component such as primengs. Gives you alot of flexibility http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Answer (score 9):

Have to do a little transformation to the list of strings, its easy, just put the array through a function that makes and returns a new array to display

[**PLUNKR**](https://plnkr.co/edit/A7JY4wR28MQcGLE0zNHb?p=preview) of my example below

### Example

**my-comp.component.ts**

```
items: any[] = ["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6","item7","item8","item9"];

buildArr(theArr: String[]): String[][]{

    var arrOfarr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < theArr.length ; i+=4) {
        var row = [];

        for(var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
          var value = theArr[i + x];
            if (!value) {
                break;
            }
            row.push(value);
        }
        arrOfarr.push(row);
    }
     return arrOfarr;
}
```

**my-comp.component.html**

```
<table id="myTable" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>Item1</th>
             <th>Item2</th>
             <th>Item3</th>
             <th>Item4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of buildArr(items)">
            <td *ngFor="let item of row">{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your array of strings in an array of array of strings:

```
this.rowList = [];
var stringList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3];
var colCount = 4;
for (var i = 0; i < stringList.length; i = i + 4) {
    var element = stringList[i];
    var row = [];
    while (row.length < colCount) {
        var value = stringList[i + row.length];
        if (!value) {
            break;
        }
        row.push(value);
    }
    this.rowList.push(row);
}
```

And then just use two ngFor:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of rowList">
            <td *ngFor="let col of row">{{col}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<thead>
   <th>..</th>
<th>..</th>
<th>..</th>
<th>..</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="for component in components | groupBy: 3">
Data here
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This will require angular-filter module/library. I had done a similar thing for [Sorting elements in AngularJS for nested ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36226421/sorting-elements-in-angularjs-for-nested-ng-repeat) question.

Comment: It's `Angular2` question, not `AngularJs`.